# How to prevent '&' from showing as '&amp' in js

Tags: javascript, mysql

I using JS a friend helped me with. I am not sure how to escape '&' that's coming from MySQL data table.

Here is the JS line I would like to put in escape for "on_off_sale" is the column that is returning '&' as '&amp'. How can I get it to display '&' rather than '&amp'

```
$('#licClass').text($('#'+curId+"-licType")[0].innerHTML.substring(0, 1) + "," + $('#'+curId+"-licType")[0].innerHTML + " (" + $('#'+curId+"-on_off_sale")[0].innerHTML +")");
```

Answer (score 3):

`&amp;` is the HTML representation of `&`.

You are reading `innerHTML` so you are getting HTML.

Then you are writing using `text()` which expects plain text input (not the HTML you are giving it).

Use `html()` instead of `text()` if your string is of HTML and not plain text.